# #1305 - FUNCTION does not exist - nested loops

Tags: mysql, for-loop, syntax-error, nested-loops

So, I'm getting an error about a function not being defined. It happens every time I try to use my counter variables to refer to specific entries in tables. I don't get it.

To be more clear, I was advised that in order to use loops with mysql I had to make a 'procedure' which I have done. the count and ingredientcount variables are references to the row being examined in the tables tDrinks and tUniqueingredients.

I am trying to generate a foreign key reference for the drink id from tDrinks in the table tDrinkMix. I want there to be an entry of the drink id for each instance of a unique ingredient in the drink.  There are 16.5k drinks and 2.2k unique ingredients.

Right now it dies on SELECT id(count) FROM tDrinks. If I remove the (count) there it dies next on WHERE d_shopping(count).

The error thrown is #1305 and it says that the function DrinksDB.id is not defined

```
DROP PROCEDURE `test`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE ingredientcount INT DEFAULT 0;
 WHILE count < 16532 DO
    WHILE ingredientcount < 2202 DO
      INSERT INTO tDrinkMix(count)
                 SELECT id(count) FROM tDrinks
                 WHERE d_shopping(count)
                  LIKE CONCAT('%',tUniqueingredients.ingredient(ingredientcount),'%');
      SET ingredientcount = ingredientcount + 1;
    END WHILE;
   SET count = count + 1;
 END WHILE;
END
```

So I'm working on refining this a bit, and I'm still not quite there. How can you tell this is my first database project? The following is getting closer I think: the procedure at least saves and looks like it might execute

```
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE ingredientcount INT DEFAULT 0;
 WHILE count < 16532 DO
    WHILE ingredientcount < 2202 DO
      INSERT INTO tDrinkMix(drink_id)

                SELECT id
                FROM tDrinks
                WHERE id = count

                and

                d_shopping

                LIKE 
                (SELECT CONCAT (ingredient,'%') FROM tUniqueingredients WHERE id = ingredientcount);

      SET ingredientcount = ingredientcount + 1;
    END WHILE;
   SET count = count + 1;
 END WHILE;
END//
```

Comment: What do you expect `id(count)` to do?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  In particular, what do want those two expressions with count to do?

Comment: I'm building a foreign key reference. I want to take the drink id and have it repeat as many times as there are ingredients. there are 16k drinks and 2k ingredients.  some drinks have up to 15 ingredients, and would have their id repeated as many times as they have ingredients. I am expecting probably 80k results when it's over

Comment: I am expecting id(count) to return the numeric value for the field 'id' where I am in the count from the table 'tDrinks' where items in the shopping list match the unique ingredients

Comment: By "where I am in the count" do you mean "row number"? If not, can you be more descriptive?

Comment: count is meant to be the row number from table tDrinks. ingredientcount is meant to be the row number from tUniqueingredients.

Comment: for insert statement first you need to prepare statement then you can execute that prepared statement as you are using variable (count) in your statement.

Comment: Your queries seem to make absolutely no sense. Could you post the table structures including the new Field you need? I doubt that you need a While... count++ construct for that - in fact the whole purpose of a database is to not manually cycle data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is occurring because the parser is interpreting id(count) as a function. It's looking for a function in your database which I guess is DrinksDB. When you remove the (count) from id its moving to the next syntax error of d_shopping(count) and looks for a function with the name d_shopping in your database.
I appreciate I'm late in coming to this (I'm just scanning open issues) so it's probably not an issue any more. If its still a problem post a comment.

Comment: If you 'believe' this should have been a comment, not an answer.